# Google Apps Script - Set Values randomly failing

Tags: google-apps-script

Someone on stack overflow from 2016 reported this issue happening in debug mode only but this isn't debug mode, it is happening in my live code (run from webapp) running in backend AND debug mode.

The frustrating thing is that this isn't every call to setValues. There is one array call to setvalues that does work (writes to the spreadsheet) higher in the script.

This code has not been modified in more than a month and was working until at least 10-26 (first failure reported 11-2).

Here is a small example:

```
function setValuesIsFailing(sheet, array, row, column){
//newIDR_SHEET.getRange(3, 9, formulaColumns.length, 2).setValues(formulaColumns);//old command this function replaces

const targetRange = sheet.getRange(row,column,array.length,array[0].length);
console.log(139,targetRange.getA1Notation());
sheet.getRange("C5").setValue("UGH");
targetRange.setValues(array);
console.log(sheet.getRange("C5").getValue());
}
```

The result of this code is the expected console log of :

```
10:46:10 AM Info    139 'I3:J49'
10:46:11 AM Error   
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 12shsTE-Mxxx

setValuesIsFailing  @ Code.gs:143
```

So line 139 implies that it does have the sheet it is writing to and then it
doesn't throw an error when told to write to those two locations (but it does
not succeed in writing to them) and after that it throws an error when asked
to read from one of the locations.

To recap:

- code was working just fine. Had not been modified for a month and was working correctly most of that month.
- setValue / setValues commands fail silently without throwing  an error (nothing is written to target)
- service spreadsheet error occurs later when trying to read from places that should have been modified by the script but were not
- Moving the problem to a new function obviously didn't fix it.

Other things I tried, logging the sheet name, reassigning a new variable to the sheet (originalyl concerned that somehow the function was losing the sheet but debugging shows that isn't the case), moving the failing piece of code to a new function for easier logging, waiting for the problem to resolve itself.

Any ideas?

=====

Solved:
It turned out that the weird behavior was caused by a failed attempt to apply data validation to the sheet.

Unlikely that anyone else will have this behavior, but I was pulling my data validations down from a sheet a single column at a time.

Either it was accepting a 2d array of one column as acceptable to the data validation setup command OR it was automatically flattening the array since it was only one column. This has changed. Manually flattening my column data with a .flat() fixed the issue. I would really have expected the bad validation setting call to throw an error though.

Comment: If you found the answer to your issue please feel free to share it as an answer so other community members that have the same problem can see how you managed to solve it.

Comment: When you get sometime please provide an answer and select the checkbox when you can. It might be helpful in case anyone else ever gets the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that a bad validation application was causing the spreadsheet to basically stop being able to be updated.

It was reading a 2d array (one column) and applying that as a validation list. When I flattened the validation list it worked.